# Mapping pg object types with jooq

Tags: jooq

I am using `jooq.fetch(q).intoMaps()` to retrieve result of a user query (q) into list of maps and it works perfectly. However for `object types` I am getting a raw string of the object itself like

```
[ {
  "node_id" : 63045,
  "node_ip" : "10.0.0.0",
  "ip_version" : "IPv4",
  "port" : 161,
  "node_name" : "test",
  "node_category" : {
    "type" : "\"cm\".\"node_category\"",
    "value" : "network",
    "null" : true
  }
]
```

How can I get just the **value** of `node_category` ?

Comment: Don't you generate the classes from the database model with jOOQ generator? There you will have a class for every object in the schema

Comment: What's `q` exactly? Are you mixing `jsonObject()` and other things with UDT references? Might be a bug, you could report one with details to reproduce here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

Comment: @LukasEder `q` is an ad-hoc query provided by the user so unfortunately it is not mapped. What I am trying to do is execute the query and return the results to user.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli unfortunately this is a dynamic sql query provided by user during runtime

Comment: But when it's dynamic you would have to parse the string by yourself. How would you know that there is node_category inside?

Comment: users basically send a query like `select * from nodes` using rest API and this is what they get as result

Comment: And what types do the columns have?

Comment: jOOQ could make that work, perhaps. Just file a bug report with hints on how to reproduce...